# Transformation of the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x+1)f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Is there a way to reduce the following functional equation

$$
f(x+y)=f(x+1)f(y),\qquad x,y>0,
$$

to the equation

$$
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),\qquad x,y>0,
$$

whose solutions are known?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For  the  same  $f$ ,  no.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x+1)$ then $g(x+y)=f(x+(y+1))=f(x+1)f(y+1)=g(x)g(y)$

Comment: For $ f :R \to R$ ,if $ f$ (or $ g$) is assumed to be continuous then $g(x)=A^x$ for some constant  $A > 0 $,( or $ g=0$  for all $ x)$. But there are many other discontinuous solutions for $g$.

Comment: I think measurability of _f_  (or _g_) suffices. Do you agree?